# Where does exim store mail? (or, where did my email go?)

Tags: exim

So, I've just set up `mail` and `mutt` and I'm happily sending emails to a gmail.com address.

I am using EXIM as my MTA.

Now, when I reply to those emails (so they get send back to my domain) I see a record that they appeared in /var/spool/mail, but `cat` doesn't seem like a very clever way to read it.

How do I properly read mail that is sent to me at my server?  How can I set up additional email addresses like `me@myserver.com`, `perry@myserver.com`, `katy-is-my-wife@myserver.com`

Links to resources would be helpful - I am searching now as I type but I'm not finding instructions just yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was [/etc/aliases](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=etc-aliases) that held the answer.

That and /etc/email-addresses

I also learned a bit from [this page.](http://web.archive.org/web/20151025193438/http://www.ahinc.com/linux101/email.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exim very well, but by default it should deliver the e-mail to either a mailbox or a Maildir in the user's home folder. The simplest way to get additional e-mail account is to setup additional users on the server (there are other ways, and you can use aliases to send multiple e-mail addresses to the same user).

Comment: So, how do I know what the Maildir will be?  And how do I change it?  'root' is running the exim process.

Comment: If it's using Maildir, it will literally be a directory named "Maildir" in their home folder. If it's a mbox format, it'll be a file ~/mbox[o,rd,cl,cl2] or a file in /var/mail/$username.

Answer (score 0):

Using exim as a POP server, the mail will be stored in `~/Maildir`. If the email account is name@example.com, the mail for that account will be stored in `~/Maildir/name`.

If the user is using exim and IMAP, the mail will instead be stored in: '~/imap/example.com/Maildir/name'.

If you are logged in as root you can't use ~ to find a user's home directory of course. On a Debian server, you'll find those directories at:
'/home/username/Maildir/name' and '/home/username/imap/example.com/Maildir/name' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (exim on Ubuntu 14.04), it's in `/var/vmail/<domain>/<account>`.

Answer (score 0):

Exim is not a mailstore, it puts it received mail wherever you tell it to. be that a file, pipe, directory, or some other SMTP server.

In your case it seems to be configured to use a per-user mbox mailspool
mutt should be able to read /var/spool/mail/yourname

If cat works mutt should also be able to access that.
Try just running `mutt`.